# Loops with an asymetric increment

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do here is to have function with a loop which would increment a number asymetricly and return it over each iteration.

- I would start with 11.
- I would increment by 2 to get 13,
- increment by 4 to get 17,
- increment by 2 to get 19,
- increment by 2 to get 21,
- increment by 2 to get 23,
- increment by 4 ....

the pattern of the incrementats would be cyclic and repeat over time:  `2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4` and so on.

I have been thinking of for and while loops, generator functions or Array.prototype.reduce but can't seem to be able to find an easy solution to my problem.

I haven't come up with any good starting point on how I should proceed...
Below is an exemple of how I would like it to work pushing the values to an array, but they could also just be returned by a function...

```
function returnNums(maxValue) {
  let returnedNums = [];
  for (let i = 11; i <= maxValue;) {
    returnedNums.push(i);
    // magical solution to increment i following my desired pattern right here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `j` variable  to iterate over the `[2, 4, 2, 2]` array and increment `i` by `arr[j % arr.length]`

```js
let arr = [2, 4, 2, 2];

function returnNums(maxValue) {
  let returnedNums = [];

  for (let i = 11, j = 0; i <= maxValue; j++) {
    returnedNums.push(i);
    // increment i following my desired pattern right here
    i += arr[j % arr.length]; 
  }
  return returnedNums;
}

console.log(returnNums(20));
console.log(returnNums(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

always increment by 2, and search a way to increment with an other 2 each 3 incrementation

```
let returnedNums = [];
let maxValue=120;
  for (let i = 11,inc=1; i <= maxValue;i+=2,inc++) {
    returnedNums.push(i);
    console.log(i);
    if(inc==2 || ((inc-3)>0 && (inc-3)%3==0)) i+=2; 
  }
```

The Output

```
 11
 13
 17
 19
 21
 23
 27
 29
 31
 35
 37
 39
 43
 45
 47
 51
 53
 55
 59
 61
 63
 67
 69
 71
 75
 77
 79
 83
 85
 87
 91
 93
 95
 99
 101
 103
 107
 109
 111
 115
 117
 119
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you "wanted increments" follow a simple equation:

- cycle of 4 (-> use modulo division `% 4`)
- one out of 4 of the values being 4 (-> use `== 0` in a conditional)
- other values the others being 2

How about this code using a generator function?

```js
const generator = (start) => {
    let current = start;
    let index   = 0;
    return () => {
        const result = current;
        current += (index++ + 3) % 4 == 0 ? 4 : 2;
        return result;
    };
};

const f = generator(11); // start value
for (;;) {
    let next = f();
    if (next > 40) // max value
        break;
    console.log(next);
}
```

Test run with Node.js:

```
$ node dummy.js
11
13
17
19
21
23
27
29
31
33
37
39
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I advise you [recursive functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/), since are a powerful way to solve problems like this:

```js
function returnNums(maxValue) {
  console.log(returnNumsRecursive(maxValue, 11, 0, [2,4,2,2], [11]));
}

function returnNumsRecursive(maxValue, value, iteration, patternArray, arrayOfValues) {
  if(iteration === patternArray.length) iteration = 0; 
  let newValue = value + patternArray[iteration];

  if(newValue > maxValue) return arrayOfValues;
  arrayOfValues.push(newValue);
  if(newValue === maxValue) return arrayOfValues;
  
  return returnNumsRecursive(maxValue, newValue, ++iteration, patternArray, arrayOfValues);
}


returnNums(50);
```

The `returnNumsRecursive` allows you to max the initial value to start the sum (11), and the `patternArray` ([2,4,2,2]) that will be used to create the sum array.

But, if you prefer a more traditional approach:

```js
function returnNums(maxValue) {
  let returnedNums = [];
  const pattern = [2,4,2,2];
  for (let i = 11, j=0; i <= maxValue; j++) {
    if(j < pattern.length - 1) j++;
    else j = 0;
    returnedNums.push(i);
    i+=pattern[j];
  }
  return returnedNums;
}

console.log(returnNums(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great ideas.

For my part I have succesfully solved my problem using some of your ideas as follows

```
let incValue;
let incCounter = 3;

function increment() {
  incCounter % 4 === 0 ? (incValue = 4) : (incValue = 2);
  incCounter += 1;
  return incValue;
}

function returnNums(maxValue) {
  let returnedNums = [];
  for (let i = 11; i <= maxValue; ) {
    returnedNums.push(i);
    i += inc();
  }
  return returnedNums;
}

returnNums(30); // => [11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
start= 11;
end = 100;
patern = [2,4,2,2]
for( i2 = 0; start <= end; start = start+patern[i2], i2++){
  if(i2 ==  patern.length) i2 =0;
  console.log(start)
}
```